# Query on how the Probability is derived in the below scenario

Tags: probability

A large pool of adults earning their first driver’s license includes 50% low-risk drivers,30% moderate-risk drivers, and 20% high-risk drivers. Because these drivers have no prior driving record, an insurance company considers each driver to be randomly selected from the pool. This month, the insurance company writes 4 new policies for adults earning their first driver’s license. What is the probability that these 4 will contain at least
two more high-risk drivers than low-risk drivers?

**the answer given is as below:**

$Pr(Z \ge (X + 2)) = f (0,0, 4) + f (1,0, 3) + f (0,1,3) + f (0,2,2)$

where $x,y,z$ in $f(x,y,z)$ are the low, moderate & high risk drivers.

**Now my question is why the possibility $f(2,0,2)$ is not taken?**

Comment: If you have $2$ high risk drivers and $2$ low risk drivers, do you have "**at least two more high-risk drivers than low risk**"?  No, because $z-x=2-2\not\geq 2$.

Comment: i am so dumb.......... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Where $x,y,z$ represent the number of low, moderate, and high risk drivers respectively, the condition: `"contain at least two more high-risk drivers than low-risk drivers"` is equivalent to the condition $z-x\geq 2$

Note that $(0,0,4)$ has $z-x=4-0=4\geq 2$,  $(1,0,3)$ has $z-x=3-1=2\geq 2$, $(0,1,3)$ has $z-x=3-0=3\geq 2$, etc...

However, $(2,0,2)$ has $z-x=2-2=0\not\geq 2$, so it does *not* satisfy the required condition.